# Maven ignoring localRepository setting in user's settings.xml

Tags: maven, vagrant, chef-infra, maven-3, chef-solo

I'm having an issue with Maven not respecting the `<localRepository>` value in my user's settings.xml file.

My environment is a Vagrant instance provisioned using Chef. I have installed Maven using the Chef Maven [cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/maven).

Maven runs fine except for the fact that it is ignoring the local repository I have defined in the ssh user's settings.xml:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ cat ~/.m2/settings.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <localRepository>/vagrant/.m2/repository</localRepository>

</settings>
```

As you can see, I am attempting to share the local repository between the Host OS and the Guest OS by placing the Maven Local Repository as a subdirectory under the folder that is shared by the Host OS and the Guest OS: `/vagrant/.m2/repository`

However, when I run Maven with the Debug option set: `mvn -X` Maven informs me that it is correctly reading the settings.xml file, but for some reason does not set the Local Repository correctly:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ mvn -X
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:47+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_65, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_65/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-85-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/local/maven/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/vagrant/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from /usr/local/maven/conf/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from /home/vagrant/.m2/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /home/vagrant/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /home/vagrant/.m2/repository
```

Maven incorrectly sets the local repository to the default `/home/vagrant/.m2/repository`.

I don't think it's an issue with the `/vagrant` folder being shared between the Guest OS and the Host OS as running `mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/vagrant/.m2/repository` works correctly.

Is there any reason why Maven would not be reading or interpreting the users settings.xml file correctly in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

As usual, explaining the problem lead me down the path to finding an answer. For anyone who stumbles across this post the issue was that the [Chef Maven Cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/maven) has a default attribute `node['maven']['mavenrc']['opts']` that is sets the value of `/etc/mavenrc/` to `-Dmaven.repo.local=$HOME/.m2/repository -Xmx384m` (as of version 2.2.0 of the Cookbook). This was overriding all configuration of the local repository that I was doing in the user's settings.xml file.

To fix this I changed the default value of this attribute in my recipe's default attributes file `attributes/default.rb` to `default[maven][mavenrc][opts] = ''`